# How to use Microsoft Coyote in F# code - protected nested attribute type in parent type

Tags: c#, f#, actor, coyote

Is there a language difference between F# and C# here that is blocking the use of Microsoft Coyote from F# code?

Because the `OnEventDoActionAttribute` is defined in the inherited type `Microsoft.Coyote.Actors.Actor` with a protected access modifier, it looks like  it is still accessible in inherited actor types in C# but not so in F#.

Hello world sample converted to F#:

```
type SetupEvent(serverId : ActorId) =
    inherit Event()
    member this.ServerId = serverId

type PingEvent(callerId : ActorId) = 
    inherit Event()
    member this.Caller = callerId

type PongEvent() =
    inherit Event()

// both attribute spec fail
//[<Microsoft.Coyote.Actors.Actor.OnEventDoAction(typeof<PingEvent>, "HandlePing")>] // Error: The type 'OnEventDoActionAttribute' is not accessible from this code location
[<OnEventDoAction(typeof<PingEvent>, "HandlePing")>] // Error: The type 'OnEventDoAction' is not defined
type Server() =
    inherit Actor()

    member this.HandlePing(e : Event) =
        let ping = e :?> PingEvent
        printfn "Server handling ping"
        printfn "Server sending pong back to caller"
        this.SendEvent(ping.Caller, new PongEvent());

// both attribute spec fail
//[<Microsoft.Coyote.Actors.Actor.OnEventDoAction(typeof<PongEvent>, "HandlePong")>] // Error: The type 'OnEventDoActionAttribute' is not accessible from this code location
[<OnEventDoAction(typeof<PongEvent>, "HandlePong")>] // Error: The type 'OnEventDoAction' is not defined
type Client() =

    inherit Actor()

    let mutable serverId : ActorId = null

    override this.OnInitializeAsync(initialEvent : Event) : System.Threading.Tasks.Task =
        printfn "%A initializing" this.Id
        serverId <- (initialEvent :?> SetupEvent).ServerId
        printfn "%A sending ping event to server" this.Id
        this.SendEvent(serverId, new PingEvent(this.Id))
        base.OnInitializeAsync(initialEvent)

    member this.HandlePong() =
        printfn "%A received pong event" this.Id

[<Test>]
let Execute (runtime : IActorRuntime) =
    let serverId = runtime.CreateActor(typeof<Server>)
    runtime.CreateActor(typeof<Client>, new SetupEvent(serverId)) |> ignore
    runtime.CreateActor(typeof<Client>, new SetupEvent(serverId)) |> ignore
    runtime.CreateActor(typeof<Client>, new SetupEvent(serverId)) |> ignore

let runtime = RuntimeFactory.Create()
Execute(runtime) |> ignore
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Not sure what to do in order to work around this issue.

LINQPad document URI to try out the code directly: http://share.linqpad.net/a9rif7.linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, they [declared](https://github.com/microsoft/coyote/blob/915b5108ae45fc5636886222cff43887c3ec34ef/Source/Core/Actors/Actor.cs#L1083) the attribute to be a `protected sealed` nested inside `Actor`. While F# cannot declare anything as `protected`, it can follow access restriction - usually people enforce access restriction for a reason.

The other way you could have done this is to have a top-level class which inherits from `Actor` and implement the clients as nested classes. But F# doesn't support nesting classes either.

I don't see any particular reason for it to be declared `protected` other than scope pollution.

Probably forking and changing the access modifier is the easiest option right now.

Comment: Afaik, F# can consume protected members, it just can't declare them. So this is a bug in F# wrt attributes.

Comment: This probably was an added feature in C#. It shouldn't behave any differently, so yeah it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it was to reduce scope pollution, and to ensure you only get intellisense for these types when you are in a valid place to use them inside Visual Studio.  Cool idea to build an F# example though...

Comment: Reasonable choice when working with C# semantics - and I didn't expect a language difference here - but perhaps this implementation characteristic could be reconsidered if there are no other more intrinsic reason that make it infeasible for F# use.

Comment: I don't know F# very well but there is no way to bridge these nested types in a way for F# to be able to use them?  I don't really want to pollute the C# namespace in order to support F#...

Comment: Cross-reference to F# compiler issue: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3172.